# Inserting multiple variables on a particular line using awk

Tags: shell, variables, awk

I want to insert a few variables (say 3) on a particular line (say 3rd line). I have the following MWE.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo  > testfile
echo  >> testfile
echo  >> testfile
v1=1; v2=2; v3=3
sed -i "3,3c\ $v1  $v2  $v3" testfile
cat testfile
```

Can I do this using `awk` just in one step? I can do

```
awk -v value=$v1 ' NR==3 {$1=value"\t"}1' testfile > tmp; mv tmp testfile
```

but that is for one variable. I have to create similar lines for `v2` and `v3`, which I don't want.

PS. In the above example, I used `echo` three times so that I could use `sed`/`awk` up to the 3rd line of empty `testfile`. Is there a cleverer way of inserting on n-th line?

Comment: `awk -v v1="$v1" -v v2="$v2" -v v3="$v3" '…program…' file`?  One of my shell scripts passes 8 variables in this way to an `awk` script.  Whether that's an entirely good idea is a separate discussion, but it is possible to pass as many variables as you need to `awk`.  This is roughly what anubhava is showing with his code in his answer.

Comment: What's a `MWE`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yeah right. `awk -v v1="$v1" -v v2="$v2" -v v3="$v3" 'NR==3 {$1=v1"\t"; $2=v2"\t"; $3=v3}1' testfile  > tmp; mv tmp testfile` works for the above example. But @anubhava's solution looks more appealing. :) 

@EdMorton MWE => Minimal Working Example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do this with an empty file:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" -v n=3 -v v1="$v1" -v v2="$v2" -v v3="$v3" 'BEGIN {
   # print n-1 empty lines
   for (i=1; i<n; i++)
      print ""
   # print v1, v2, v3
   print v1, v2, v3
}'
```

Comment: Very nice. I didn't think about  using `BEGIN`. Btw does the second `print` command terminate the for-loop?

Comment: No 2nd print is invoked after `for` loop completes.

Comment: @anubhave I think I meant the same. The `for` loop doesn't allow two `print` commands consecutively in the same loop.

Comment: for loop will allow any number of print if you wrap them inside `{...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Use `-v` to define variables at the shell-level.

```
awk -v v1="$one" -v v2="$two" -v v3="$three" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print "\n\n" v1, v2, v3}'
```